# Distance between GPS Points

Tags: java, math, distance

I'm trying to calculate the distance between two points in km.

However I think my formular might be wrong, I've calculated the distance with Google Maps (so I think I have valid test data)

### Testdata

**Position 1:** 50.123248, 8.847602

**Position 2:** 50.120132, 8.841926

**Distance (according to Google Maps):** 531,34 m

## My approach

```
public double distanceTo(Location location) {
    final int EARTH_RADIUS_KM = 6371;

    double lng1 = this.longitude;
    double lng2 = location.getLongitude();
    double lat1 = this.latitude;
    double lat2 = location.getLatitude();

    double theta = lng1 - lng2;

    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));

    dist = Math.acos(dist);

    dist = rad2deg(dist);

    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;

    dist = dist * 1.609344; //for Kilometers

    return (dist);

}

/**
 * decimal degrees to radians
 *
 * @param deg
 * @return
 */
private double deg2rad(double deg) {

    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);

}


/**
 * radians to decimal degrees
 *
 * @param rad
 * @return
 */
private double rad2deg(double rad) {

    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);

}
```

Testcase:

```
@Before
public void setup() {

    location1 = new Location(50.123248, 8.847602);
    location2 = new Location(50.120132, 8.841926);


}

@Test
public void testDistanceTo() {
//TODO No real assertion yet
    System.out.print(location1.distanceTo(location2));

// Expecting 531,34 m - 0.531 KM
}
```

but the actual result is `0.7179858613314315`

Comment: Is this necessary?
`public class Location {

    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    public Location(double lng, double lat) {

        this.longitude = lng;
        this.latitude = lat;

    }`

+ the above methods for distance and getter/setters. :)

Comment: Are you mixing up latitude and longitude in your `Location` constructor?  Why do you declare `EARTH_RADIUS_KM`, but instead of using it, convert it to miles with presumably a miles per degree factor, then convert it to kilometers?

Comment: @rgettman yes, mixed up latitude and longitude! Sorry for the inconvenience! And thanks for the tip.

Comment: [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: There are enough answers to guide you to formulas you could use. But if you want to know where specifically your formula went wrong, you should state the formula you use more clearly (i.e. without all the `Math.` and `deg2rad`) so that it fits in a single line, and you should also explain which references and which considerations led you to that formula.